# dictionary values to excel columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I would like to convert a dictionary of key-value pairs to an excel file with column names that match the values to the corresponding columns.

For example :

I have an excel file with column names as:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g and h.
```

I have a dictionary like: 
    {`1:['c','d'],2:['a','h'],3:['a','b','b','f']}`.

I need the output to be:

```
       a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h

1            1  1                

2      1                    1

3      1  2           1
```

the `1,2,3` are the keys from the dictionary.
The rest of the columns could be either `0` or `null`.

I have tried splitting the dictionary and am getting

```
1 = ['c','d']
2 = ['a','h']
3 = ['a','b','b','f']
```

but, I don't know how to pass this to match with the excel file.

Comment: What is the data type of your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with `pandas` and `collections` (there may exist a more efficient solution):

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
d = {...} # Your dictionary
series = pd.Series(d) # Convert the dict into a Series
counts = series.apply(Counter) # Count items row-wise
counts = counts.apply(pd.Series) # Convert the counters to Series
table = counts.fillna(0).astype(int) # Fill the gaps and make the counts integer
print(table)
#   a  b  c  d  f  h
1  0  0  1  1  0  0
2  1  0  0  0  0  1
3  1  2  0  0  1  0
```

It is not clear what *type* of output you expect, so I leave it to you to convert the DataFrame to the output of your choice.

Comment: The compound statement assigning table is quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution only based on standard lists and dictionaries. It generates a 2D list, which is then easy to convert into a CSV file than can be loaded by Excel.

```
d = {1:['c','d'],2:['a','h'],3:['a','b','b','f']}

cols = dict((c,n) for n,c in enumerate('abcdefgh'))
rows = dict((k,n) for n,k in enumerate('123'))
table = [[0 for col in cols] for row in rows]

for row, values in d.items():
    for col in values:
        table[rows[row]][cols[col]] += 1

print(table)

# output:
# [[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], [1,2,0,0,0,1,0,0]]
```